# RXJava2: correct pattern to chain retrofit requests

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am relatively new to RXJava in general (really only started using it with RXJava2), and most documentation I can find tends to be RXJava1; I can usually translate between both now, but the entire Reactive stuff is so big, that it's an overwhelming API with good documentation (when you can find it). I'm trying to streamline my code, an I want to do it with baby steps. The first problem I want to solve is this common pattern I do a lot in my current project:

You have a Request that, if successful, you will use to make a second request.

If either fails, you need to be able to identify which one failed. (mostly to display custom UI alerts).

This is how I usually do it right now:

(omitted the `.subscribeOn/observeOn` for simplicity)

```
Single<FirstResponse> first = retrofitService.getSomething();

first
   .subscribeWith(
     new DisposableSingleObserver<FirstResponse>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(final FirstResponse firstResponse) {

               // If FirstResponse is OK…
                Single<SecondResponse> second = 
                 retrofitService
                    .getSecondResponse(firstResponse.id) //value from 1st
                    .subscribeWith(
                      new DisposableSingleObserver<SecondResponse>() {

                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess(final SecondResponse secondResponse) {
                              // we're done with both!
                           }

                           @Override
                            public void onError(final Throwable error) {
                            //2nd request Failed, 
                            }                        
                     });

         }

         @Override
         public void onError(final Throwable error) {
              //firstRequest Failed, 
         }
      });
```

Is there a better way to deal with this in RXJava2?

I've tried `flatMap` and variations and even a `Single.zip` or similar, but I'm not sure what the easiest and most common pattern is to deal with this.

In case you're wondering FirstRequest will fetch an actual `Token` I need in the SecondRequest. Can't make second request without the token.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest using flat map (And [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) if that is an option).
Also you do not need to keep the return value (e.g `Single<FirstResponse> first`) if you are not doing anything with it.

```
retrofitService.getSomething()
    .flatMap(firstResponse -> retrofitService.getSecondResponse(firstResponse.id)
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<SecondResponse>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(final SecondResponse secondResponse) {
            // we're done with both!
         }

         @Override
          public void onError(final Throwable error) {
             // a request request Failed, 
          }                        
   });
```

[This](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/) article helped me think through styles in how I structure RxJava in general. You want your chain to be a list of high level actions if possible so it can be read as a sequence of actions/transformations.

**EDIT**
Without lambdas you can just use a `Func1` for your flatMap. Does the same thing just a lot more boiler-plate code.

```
retrofitService.getSomething()
    .flatMap(new Func1<FirstResponse, Observable<SecondResponse> {
        public void Observable<SecondResponse> call(FirstResponse firstResponse) {
            return retrofitService.getSecondResponse(firstResponse.id)
        }
    })
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<SecondResponse>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(final SecondResponse secondResponse) {
            // we're done with both!
         }

         @Override
          public void onError(final Throwable error) {
             // a request request Failed, 
          }                        
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's what I had in mind (unfortunately I do not have Retrolambda on this project) would you mind helping me unravel the lambda simplification?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I added an example without the lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, I got it working. Just for the record this is RXJava2, so `Func1` is `Function`.

Answer (score 3):

Does this not work for you?

```
retrofitService
.getSomething()
.flatMap(firstResponse -> retrofitService.getSecondResponse(firstResponse.id))
.doOnNext(secondResponse -> {/* both requests succeeded */})
/* do more stuff with the response, or just subscribe */
```

Comment: It may do, but where would I catch an error with firstResponse? (Also, I can's retrolambda in this project, unfortunately).

Comment: What would you do with the error once you caught it?

Comment: Specifically notify the UI (the firstResponse is a token, failure to obtain it, requires the UI to react differently). The presenter (in charge of this data interaction) will need to do different things if the token failed. The 2nd call is using the token, and, again, will end up in a different UI state. Does it make sense?

Comment: Sure; I'd do it via `.onErrorResumeNext(e -> {updateUIState(e); return Observable.empty();})`. Or even `.doOnError(e -> updateUIState(e))`, if you're OK with collecting all the errors in your subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for that, I can't accept both answers and I ended up using the other one, but this is very handy. I appreciate it :)