# Retrofit handle multiple calls with response value stored an reused

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm here with a new question about Android and Retrofit. I was wondering what is the correct way to handle multiple async calls on a Android Activity and each of this one, onResponse returns a value used by the next call, because if I understood fine, the calls runs on background which means that if the call didn't finish you returned value will be null until you get a successful response.

I was thinking to achieve that with something like this(only the basis):

```
private List<SomeModel> mylist;
final Call<List<SomeModel>> call1 = client.getSomeValues1();
final Call<List<SomeModel2>> call2 = client.getSomeValues2();

call1.enqueue(new Callback<SomeModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(SomeModel> call, Response<SomeModel> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set mylist to response.body()
                            mylist = response.body();
                        } 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SomeModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        mylist = null;
                    }
                });


call2.enqueue(new Callback<SomeModel2>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(SomeModel2> call, Response<SomeModel2> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Do something with my list and also with call2 response

                            if(mylist != null) {
                                for (SomeModel singleObject: mylist) {
                                    // Do something with each object
                                }
                            }

                        } 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SomeModel2> call, Throwable t) {
                        // Do something with fail call
                    }
                });
```

With something like the example before because the calls are running on background and maybe the call2 finish first then mylist value will be null because call1 hasn't finished yet.

Also I was thinking to put call2 inside call1 onResponse but I don't feel that right. I have to say that I'm still learning, I'm pretty rookie.

So, What is the correct why to handle this and how? Thanks. I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Use RxJava to pipe the api calls.

Comment: Yes, enqueue call2 when `call1.onResponse` is called

Comment: Thanks for your answers, @insa_c can you explain me how can I achieve that with rxjava2 ?

Comment: [Kotlin chaining api calls using rxjava](https://medium.com/@adinugroho/chaining-multiple-retrofit-call-using-rxjava-177b64c8103e) check this tutorial, it is in Kotlin but you should be fine.
Alternatively you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355395/rxjava2-correct-pattern-to-chain-retrofit-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion @insa_c
I achieved that with RXJava2, here is how I did it explained general way:

First you need to define your api services as Observables

```
@GET("url-1/")
Observable<List<Model1>> service1();

@GET("url-2/")
Observable<List<Model2>> service2();
```

Now in your activity make the calls this way:

```
final Observable<List<Model1>> call1 = APIClient.getClient().create(APIService.class).service1();

final Observable<List<Model2>> call2 = APIClient.getClient().create(APIService.class).service2();
```

Now lets make an unique observable with zip (I used a List because I'm adding two different kind of objects to the list that I'll get when both calls finish):

```
<Observable<List<Object>> test = Observable.zip(call1, call2, new BiFunction<List<Model1>, List<Model2>, List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public List<Object> apply(List<Model1> objects1, List<Model2> objects2) throws Exception {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(objects1);
        list.addAll(objects2);
        return list;
    }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Now the only thing left to do is to subscribe and decide what you want to do with the content of both responses:

```
test.subscribe(new Observer<List<?>>() {

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onSubscribe");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<?> objects) {
        // You can split the list by object in here with an instanceof to determine if it's Model1 or Model2
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        // Do something here, both calls finished, if you stored something in onNext method you can use it here.
    }

});
```

I hope this info will be helpful for someone.